# How to delete first line(header) and last line(trailer) of a file using batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file

Source file C:/Employee.txt is as follows

```
00 02/10/2012
01,ABC,Engineer,Toyota
01,DEF,Tech Lead,Toyota
99 02/10/2012 002
```

```
Where, 
first line is a header (00 - header)
Next two lines is a body (01-body)
Last Line is trailer (99-trailer)
```

I am trying to delete first line(header) and last line(trailer) of a file and storing body in another file using batch script.New file should be as follows

```
New File C:/New.txt 
01,ABC,Engineer,Toyota
01,DEF,Tech Lead,Toyota
```

Kindly help me out

Answer (score 1):

use `findstr` to match 00 or 99 at the beginning of the line and print only **non matched** lines. `help findstr` will show you all switches, and there is an excellent description of the tool [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8844868/what-are-the-undocumented-features-and-limitations-of-the-windows-findstr-comman)